# Not getting expected output from java String split method

Tags: java, string, split

I have a string say, "1.0+20*30.2-4.0/10.1" which I want to split in such a way that I will have a string array say

```
strArr = {"1.0", "20", "30.2", "4.0",10.1}
```

I wrote the following code for this

```
public class StringSplitDemo {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "1.0+20*30.2-4.0/10.1";
    String[] strArr = (str.split("[\\+-/\\*]"));
    for(int i=0;i<strArr.length;i++)
      System.out.print(strArr[i]+" ");
  }
}
```

Rather than printing the expected output(by me) i.e 1.0 20 30.2 4.0 10.1 it prints

```
output: 1 0 20 30 2 4 0 10 1
```

which seems to split the string also around "." even if I didn't include it in the regex pattern.

What I'm missing here?
What is the right way to do this?

Comment: `str.split("[-+/*]")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
String str = "1.0+20*30.2-4.0/10.1";
String[] strArr = str.split("[-+/*]");
System.out.print(Arrays.toString(strArr));
```

See the [online Java demo](http://ideone.com/gEW5BX)

The `[\\+-/\\*]` character class matches more than just the 4 chars you defined, as `-` created a range between `+` and `/`.

[image]

You could fix the regex by escaping the hyphen, but the pattern looks much cleaner when you put the `-` at the start (or end) of the character class, where you do not have to escape it as there, the hyphen is treated as a literal `-`.

Comment: You are right. It will be cleaner without using any escape symbol.

Comment: Thanks @Wiktor for your help;

Answer (score 0):

The issue was in regex

So you need to escape **+** otherwise it will treat it as atleast once

```
String[] strArr = (str.split("[\\-/\\*\\+]"));
```

By the way escape symbol here is not required. It can simply be written as

```
String[] strArr = (str.split("[-/*+]"));
```

Comment: Inside a character class, only the `-` out of these 4 symbols needs to be escaped, and only when placed not in the final positions.